# Objective-C - Passing NSManagedObject from one page to another?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Let's say in page A I have an array of `NSManagedObjects`, user selects a cell and I navigate to a new UIViewController to display more details about the selected NSManagedObject.

```
newViewController.myManagedObject = selectedManagedObject;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
[newViewController release];
```

Ususally I would set the property for passed object to assign because I am the owner of the NSObject?
Does this apply to NSManagedObjects since the owner is Core-Data instead of me?
Should the property for this NSManagedObject be `retain` or `assign`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DetailViewController should retain the object.

More then one object can be the owner of another object. Imaging it of being the owner of the leash and not the owner of the dog attached to the leash. So many people can attach a leash to the dog, and as soon as all people detached their leash, the dog is free and has no owner anymore.

In your scenario core data could release the object (detach it's leash), as long as your code is retaining the object (on leash is attached), the object won't be deallocated (the dog can't run away).